# Win XP SP3 PC not displayed in Windows 7 network diagram but accessible. Why?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I've got a new Windows 7 PC added to my LAN.
I have two Windows XP (SP3) PCs connected to it also and one of them is visible but when I go into:
Control Panel>Network and Internet>Network Map  that XP machine is listed as "discovered device(s) could not be placed on map.

And the 2nd XP machine (also SP3) doesn't even show up at all.

However, both XP Machines are accessible  if I browse through Windows Exlorer to Network and expand that branch. But if I click on Network they are not shown in the Detail pane to the right.

All computers are:

- Up to date (XP machines on SP3)
- in the same workgroup
- Win 7 PC can browse to the XP machines but they don't show up properly in the Network diagram which makes me think something is amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows XP machine that doesn't show up had **Simple Network Sharing** enabled. Turned that off, restarted it and now it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the LLTD Responder on the other PC? I'm unsure if this is included in Windows XP SP3.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4F01A31D-EE46-481E-BA11-37F485FA34EA&displaylang=en

Comment: Yes, LLTD Responder is included with SP3. (When I tried to install it previous to asking this question it said that it was already included with SP3 (already installed)